# The loop using the "after" method doesn't run, and another problem appears

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, time

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

window=tk.Tk()
window.title("timer")
window.geometry("640x400+100+100")

setting = tk.Frame(window)
counter = tk.Frame(window)

setting.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
counter.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
setting.tkraise()

#show set
set_hmc = 0

def setcount_up():
    global set_hmc
    set_hmc += 1
    set.config(text=set_hmc)


def setcount_down():
    global set_hmc
    if set_hmc != 0:
        set_hmc -= 1
        set.config(text=set_hmc)


set_exp = tk.Label(setting, text="set", width=10, height=5)
set = tk.Label(setting, text=set_hmc, width=10, height=5)
set_up = tk.Button(setting, text="+", command=setcount_up)
set_down = tk.Button(setting, text="-", command=setcount_down)

set_exp.place(x=320,y=50)
set.place(x=320,y=100)
set_up.place(x=50,y=100)
set_down.place(x=590,y=100)


#show exercise time
exz_sec = 0

def exzcount_up():
    global exz_sec
    global exz_hmc
    exz_sec += 1
    exz_hmc = f'{exz_sec//60:02d}:{exz_sec%60:02d}'
    exz.config(text=exz_hmc)


def exzcount_down():
    global exz_sec
    global exz_hmc
    if exz_sec != 0:
        exz_sec -= 1
        exz_hmc = f'{exz_sec//60:02d}:{exz_sec%60:02d}'
        exz.config(text=exz_hmc)
 

exz_hmc = f'{exz_sec//60}:{exz_sec%60}'

exz_exp = tk.Label(setting, text="exercise", width=10, height=5)
exz = tk.Label(setting, text=exz_hmc, width=10, height=5)
exz_up = tk.Button(setting, text="+", command=exzcount_up)
exz_down = tk.Button(setting, text="-", command=exzcount_down)

exz_exp.place(x=320,y=150)
exz.place(x=320,y=200)
exz_up.place(x=50,y=200)
exz_down.place(x=590,y=200)

#show rest time
rest_sec = 0
rest_hmc = f'{rest_sec//60}:{rest_sec%60}'

def restcount_up():
    global rest_sec
    global rest_hmc
    rest_sec += 1
    rest_hmc = f'{rest_sec//60:02d}:{rest_sec%60:02d}'
    rest.config(text=rest_hmc)


def restcount_down():
    global rest_sec
    global rest_hmc
    if rest_sec != 0:
        rest_sec -= 1
        rest_hmc = f'{rest_sec//60:02d}:{rest_sec%60:02d}'
        rest.config(text=rest_hmc)



rest_exp = tk.Label(setting, text="rest", width=10, height=5)
rest = tk.Label(setting, text=rest_hmc, width=10, height=5)
rest_up = tk.Button(setting, text="+", command=restcount_up)
rest_down = tk.Button(setting, text="-", command=restcount_down)

rest_exp.place(x=320,y=250)
rest.place(x=320,y=300)
rest_up.place(x=50,y=300)
rest_down.place(x=590,y=300)

#execute button
def execute():
    counter.tkraise()
    counting()


exct = tk.Button(setting, text="execute", command=execute)
exct.place(x=320,y=350)

###############################################counting time by counter##########################################

set_count = set_hmc
cur = 5


cur_set = tk.Label(counter, text=set_count, width=10, height=5)
cur_what = tk.Label(counter, text='ready', width=10, height=5)
cur_time = tk.Label(counter, text=f'{cur//60}:{cur%60}', width=10, height=5)

cur_set.place(x=320,y=50)
cur_what.place(x=320,y=100)
cur_time.place(x=320,y=200)

def counting():
    global set_count
    global cur
    while set_count != 0:
        cur_set.config(text=set_count)

        if set_count == set_hmc:            #give user time to get ready on first set
            countdown()
        
        cur = exz_sec
        cur_what.config(text='exercise')
        countdown()

        cur = rest_sec
        cur_what.config(text='rest')
        countdown()

        set_count -= 1

        if set_count == 0:
            setting.tkraise()

def countdown():
    global cur
    if cur > 0:
        cur_time.config(text=f'{cur//60:02d}:{cur%60:02d}')
        cur -= 1
        window.after(1000, countdown)

window.mainloop()
```

[image][image]
I'm making interval timer using tkinter and python. But when I run the code, time loop using after method doesn't work. Time doesn't pass and number stays 00:05. Also, number of set become 0 regardless of what I wrote.

When I changed:

`set.config(text=set_hmc)`

and

`set = tk.Label(setting, text=set_hmc, width=10, height=5)`

to:

`set_var.set(exz_hmc)`

and

`set = tk.Label(setting, textvariable=set_var, width=10, height=5)`

And same on `exz` and rest, set number on second frame displayed normally, but time didn't passed on this too.

Comment: When I run your code, `countdown` is never called, so of course the `after`loop doesn't run. When `counting` is first called, `set_count` is zero, so none of the body of that function runs. I think you need to do some basic debugging before asking for help here.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is due to the use of a while loop in the counting function. The while loop doesn't allow the Tkinter main loop to continue processing events, so the GUI becomes unresponsive.

Instead of using a while loop, you can use the after method to schedule the countdown function at regular intervals.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("timer")
window.geometry("640x400+100+100")

setting = tk.Frame(window)
counter = tk.Frame(window)

setting.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
counter.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
setting.tkraise()

# show set
set_hmc = 0

def setcount_up():
    global set_hmc
    set_hmc += 1
    set_var.set(set_hmc)

def setcount_down():
    global set_hmc
    if set_hmc != 0:
        set_hmc -= 1
        set_var.set(set_hmc)

set_exp = tk.Label(setting, text="set", width=10, height=5)
set_var = tk.StringVar()
set_var.set(set_hmc)
set = tk.Label(setting, textvariable=set_var, width=10, height=5)
set_up = tk.Button(setting, text="+", command=setcount_up)
set_down = tk.Button(setting, text="-", command=setcount_down)

set_exp.place(x=320, y=50)
set.place(x=320, y=100)
set_up.place(x=50, y=100)
set_down.place(x=590, y=100)

# show exercise time
exz_sec = 0

def exzcount_up():
    global exz_sec
    exz_sec += 1
    exz_var.set(f'{exz_sec//60:02d}:{exz_sec%60:02d}')

def exzcount_down():
    global exz_sec
    if exz_sec != 0:
        exz_sec -= 1
        exz_var.set(f'{exz_sec//60:02d}:{exz_sec%60:02d}')

exz_var = tk.StringVar()
exz_var.set(f'{exz_sec//60:02d}:{exz_sec%60:02d}')

exz_exp = tk.Label(setting, text="exercise", width=10, height=5)
exz = tk.Label(setting, textvariable=exz_var, width=10, height=5)
exz_up = tk.Button(setting, text="+", command=exzcount_up)
exz_down = tk.Button(setting, text="-", command=exzcount_down)

exz_exp.place(x=320, y=150)
exz.place(x=320, y=200)
exz_up.place(x=50, y=200)
exz_down.place(x=590, y=200)

# show rest time
rest_sec = 0

def restcount_up():
    global rest_sec
    rest_sec += 1
    rest_var.set(f'{rest_sec//60:02d}:{rest_sec%60:02d}')

def restcount_down():
    global rest_sec
    if rest_sec != 0:
        rest_sec -= 1
        rest_var.set(f'{rest_sec//60:02d}:{rest_sec%60:02d}')

rest_var = tk.StringVar()
rest_var.set(f'{rest_sec//60:02d}:{rest_sec%60:02d}')

rest_exp = tk.Label(setting, text="rest", width=10, height=5)
rest = tk.Label(setting, textvariable=rest_var, width=10, height=5)
rest_up = tk.Button(setting, text="+", command=restcount_up)
rest_down = tk.Button(setting, text="-", command=restcount_down)

rest_exp.place(x=320, y=250)
rest.place(x=320, y=300)
rest_up.place(x=50, y=300)
rest_down.place(x=590, y=300)

# execute button
def execute():
    counter.tkraise()
    counting()

exct = tk.Button(setting, text="execute", command=execute)
exct.place(x=320, y=350)

############################################### counting time by counter##########################################

set_count = set_hmc
cur = 5

cur_set = tk.Label(counter, textvariable=set_var, width=10, height=5)
cur_what = tk.Label(counter, text='ready', width=10, height=5)
cur_time = tk.Label(counter, text=f'{cur//60:02d}:{cur%60:02d}', width=10, height=5)

cur_set.place(x=320, y=50)
cur_what.place(x=320, y=100)
cur_time.place(x=320, y=200)

def counting():
    global set_count
    global cur

    if set_count > 0:
        cur_set.config(text=set_count)

        if set_count == set_hmc:  # give user time to get ready on the first set
            countdown()

        cur = exz_sec
        cur_what.config(text='exercise')
        countdown()

        cur = rest_sec
        cur_what.config(text='rest')
        countdown()

        set_count -= 1

        window.after(1000, counting)  # schedule the counting function after 1000 milliseconds

    if set_count == 0:
        setting.tkraise()

def countdown():
    global cur
    if cur > 0:
        cur_time.config(text=f'{cur//60:02d}:{cur%60:02d}')
        cur -= 1
        window.after(1000, countdown)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I understood what was wrong with my code. But your code doesn't run well. When I press execute button on the window, frame doesn't change. I can't find out what's wrong. Your code seems perfect to me. Can you help me with this for the last time?

Comment: Sure, ask what's your question.

Comment: When I run the code, window pops up normally. But when I click execute button nothing happens. Frame doesn't change to "counter". Because method that changes frame works before counting() and what were changed by you are mostly in counting(), there's no reason for frame change method getting into trouble. I can't find out what's wrong. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @HyoJaeShin I think this answer is just a copy-paste from ChatGPT. The person who posted it may not have even read it.

Comment: oh... Do you know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: @HyoJaeShin Have you ever tried to follow what Bryan advices: *"do some basic debugging"*?  When `counting()` is executed, what is the value of `set_count`?